# full-sized image in popup

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox, popup

I'm using ListBox with custom DataTemplate, in this DataTemplate I have two thumbnails, when user clicks on one of this images I need to display a popup with a full-sized image(something like lightbox in JavaScript). I tried to use the Popup control in the DataTemplate, but the popup is positioned to current element on ListBox, not centered in the screen, and I'm not able to make it modal. I also tried to use the Coding4Fun toolkit, but I can't find any documentation or do it without any help.

Here is code of listbox:

```
<ListBox MaxHeight="600" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="LooksList" u:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding FetchMoreDataCommand}" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,62">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:LookListItem />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And views:LookListItem:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Margin="0,53,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PhotosPanel" Margin="20,11,0,0" Width="198" Height="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="93" Height="126">
                <Image Source="{Binding Photo1.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tap="Image_Tap" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="93" Height="126">
                <Image Source="{Binding Photo2.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Photo1 and Photo2 should be clickable and after click it should be a popup.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show what code you have and how the output differs from what you're trying to achieve. Describing your failing code and asking for someone to provide a solution doesn't make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can go about doing this. I'll show how you can do this with a little code behind.

In your xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ItemTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}"
             SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
        <Grid>
            <ToggleButton Content="X" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=Popup, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Image x:Name="PopupImage"/>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

In your code behind:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    MyImageObject obj = (MyImageObject)listBox.SelectedItem;
    ImagePopup.Source = MyImageObjct.LargeImageSource;
    Popup.IsOpen = true;
    // Unselect item so user can "reselect" it -- If you need item later, save it somewhere
    listBox.SelectedItem = null;
}

// Handle the back key button to close the popup
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(Popup.IsOpen)
    {
        Popup.IsOpen = false;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE BASED ON LATEST INFO**
If you do not need your view in a separate UserControl (no logic, only placement of controls) you can still use the example, but instead of listening to the SelectionChanged event, listen to the Tap event of each Image.

```
<ListBox MaxHeight="600" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="LooksList"
         BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,62">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Margin="0,53,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PhotosPanel" Margin="20,11,0,0" Width="198" Height="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="93" Height="126">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Photo1.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tap="Image1_Tap" />
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="93" Height="126">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Photo2.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Tap="Image2_Tap" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The event of for Tap events would look something like

```
    private void Image1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs gestureEventArgs)
    {
        MyImageObject obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as MyImageObject;
        // This is the event for Image1 Thumb, so show the Image1 Large
        ShowPopup(obj.Photo1.Large);
    }
```

If you do need a separate UserControl
You could create an "ImageOverlay" view much like in my [Custom MessageBox Post](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2011/11/13/Creating-a-Custom-MessageBox-for-Windows-Phone-Applications.aspx). In your LookListItem view subscribe to the tap event for both thumbs

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Margin="0,53,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel x:Name="PhotosPanel" Margin="20,11,0,0" Width="198" Height="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="93" Height="126">
            <Image Source="{Binding Photo1.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tap="Thumb1_Tap" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="93" Height="126">
            <Image Source="{Binding Photo2.Thumb}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tap="Thumb2_Tap" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

In the tap events show the ImageOverlay control

```
    private void Thumb1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs gestureEventArgs)
    {
        ShowOverlay(Photo1.Large);
    }

    private void Thumb2_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs gestureEventArgs)
    {
        ShowOverlay(Photo2.Large);
    }

    private void ShowOverlay(ImageSource source)
    {
        ImageOverlay overlay = new ImageOverlay();
        overlay.ImageSource = source;
        overlay.Show();
    }
```

Comment: It could be good solution, when I'd have only one picture per list item, but I have two. I think that it is impossible to decide which image was clicked in SelectionChanged event.

Comment: Thanks:) I managed to gain my aim, unfortunately I'll need some logic in my item view. I made popup outside listBox and then put it into datacontext of each item. When user tap image I show this popup with proper image:)